# Error al instalar Webmin en ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Hola tengo un problema al instalar webmin en ubuntu, al correr este script

```
sudo apt install python apt-show-versions libapt-pkg-perl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
```

me sale este error: 
**E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.**

al ejecutar:  df -h:  muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al ejecutar df -i muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien podria ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo descargas

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.900_all.deb
```

lo instalas

```
sudo apt install ./webmin_1.900_all.deb
```

y en el navegador

```
https://localhost:10000/
```

esto es por si te hacen falta los paquetes:

```
sudo apt install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python
```

pero intenta sin esto ultimo.

Comment: El error que esta indicando es debido a temas de espacio en disco duro. De hecho tiene la particion de raiz `/` completa. Puede que necesite formatear el equipo de otra manera, pero no parece que tenga que ver con la forma de instalarlo.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es activar los repositorios `universe`, `multiverse`, ya que en los actuales no reconocen a libauthen-pam-perl, etc

1. Agregas los repositorios mencionados:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

2. Agregas el repositorio de webmin:

```
deb https://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
```

3. Bajas las firma:

```
wget https://download.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
```

4. Validas la firma:

```
apt-key add jcameron-key.asc
sudo apt update
sudo apt install webmin
```